# send prop after apollo query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

After the apollo-client update I can not send a prop to the parent component.
What I do is

```
  <Query query={GET_DOG_PHOTO} variables={{ breed }}>
   {({ loading, error, data }) => {
  if (loading) return null;
  if (error) return `Error!: ${error}`;

  return (
    <img src={data.dog.displayImage} style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} />
  );
}}
```

I need to send a function after the query has been made

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here a github issue in react-apollo asking for the ability to pass a callback to a query: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/208

The workaround brought up in the issue is basically to use componentWillReceiveProps (componentDidUpdate would probably be what you'd use now, or getDerivedStateFromProps if you're just looking to set state). Little annoying, because you'll have to pass the Query loading value through as a prop so you can get into a lifecycle. So something like this

```
<Query query={GET_DOG_PHOTO} variables={{ breed }}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => (
    <LifecycleComp loading={loading} error={error} data={data} />
  )}
</Query>

class LifecycleComp extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.loading && !this.props.loading) {
      // perform callback
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) return `Error!: ${error}`;

    return (
      <img ... /> 
    )
  }
}
```